# Range object's Range object

Tags: excel, range, vba

How should we interpretate the following?

```
Range("A2:A3").Range("E2:E3").Select
```

I can't imagine, how comes the result of above code. I have tried to test it on several times, but I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a relative reference. In this case, you would select E3:E4 because Excel would assume that your active range starts at A2 (ie A2 = A1).

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff834676.aspx

> When applied to a Range object, the property is relative to the Range
>   object. For example, if the selection is cell C3, then
>   Selection.Range("B1") returns cell D3 because it’s relative to the
>   Range object returned by the Selection property. On the other hand,
>   the code ActiveSheet.Range("B1") always returns cell B1.